# AWS API Gateway not reverse proxying correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, reverse-proxy, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use AWS API Gateway as a reverse HTTP proxy to front several prototype web applications which are deployed as elastic beanstalk apps:

## Configuration

Each EB app is mapped in API Gateway under it's app name e.g.

```
/hello1 (API Gateway mapping) --> prototype1 EB application 
/hello2 (API Gateway mapping) --> prototype2 EB application
... etc
```

This is the overall mapping I have created:

[image]

It seems that API Gateway treats requests for the root resource in each mapping e.g. '/' differently to requests for sub resources, so I have set up proxy mappings for both:

The root ('/') resource is a straight forward (i.e. non-greedy) proxy mapping:

[image: Root '/' resource proxy mapping]

Then there's a greedy proxy mapping for anything underneath the root context:

[image: Greedy proxy mapping under the root context]

I then deploy the API to a stage named 'master'

The idea being that to access each prototype I'd GET the URL `http://protos.acme.com/<stage>/<proto_name>` e.g. `http://protos.acme.com/master/hello1`.

## Problem

I'm finding that if I add a trailing slash to the URL, or specify a particular resource e.g. `index.html` then everything works perfectly e.g.

- http://protos.acme.com/master/hello1/ - works fine
- http://protos.acme.com/master/hello1/index.html - works file

However if I omit the trailing slash from the URL e.g. `http://protos.acme.com/master/hello1` then the URL rewriting done by API Gateway stops working and any URLs in the proxied content no longer resolve correctly as they omit the prototype name e.g. `http://protos.acme.com/master/index.html`.

I can't find any way to configure the behaviour for when the trailing slash is omitted and I don't think it's acceptable to force my users to always remember the trailing slash.

Grateful for any insight!

Edd

Comment: Can you share the integration endpoint your are using in the 'non-greedy' ANY method? What you've configured should work assuming that method is correct.

Comment: I've tested and confirmed that the above configuration works for me. Please provide how you've configured the endpoint URL for both your greedy and non-greedy methods.

Answer (score 3):

I setup a quick test and it seems to work if I explicitly define a `GET` method at the resource root path in addition to the `ANY` `{proxy+}` path.

[image: api gateway proxy integration]

Comment: Hey Dave, I've tried re-configuring to match your example but I'm not sure how you've configured the 2 GET methods. I presumed you configured them as HTTP integrations but have you configured proxying etc (and if so what URL did you configure in each case?). Thanks!

Comment: For the `GET` method I used the HTTP Proxy Integration and the url `http://example.tld/`. For the `ANY` `{proxy+}` path I used the HTTP Proxy Integration and the url
`http://example.tld/{proxy}`.

Comment: I had a similar issue with SonarQube where sub.domain.com would show missing "missing token" but not root url's e.g 'sub.domain.com/anything' would proxy.  This fixed my issue.  I also added the path's like @DaveMaple

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, am using AWS API gateway with custom domain and aws-serverless-proxy to handle the api in the node.js backend.

If my custom domain URL - https://host.com, basepath - test, 
then with proxy integration the valid accessible url - https://host.com/test/ (With slash)

So, I am redirecting the url in the backend, if the incoming req url doesn't end with '/'.

Sample code: Reads the incoming request and redirects the response to the same url but add slash at the end.

```
let requestUrl = req.url;
    if (requestUrl !== undefined && !(requestUrl.endsWith('/'))) {
        res.writeHead(302, { 'Location': `${req.url}/` });
        res.end();
    }
```